# Проверка логина и пароля + регистрация PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, sqlite3, qt-designer

Хочу сделать *форму регистрации и входа с датабазой*, чтобы например когда я зарегистрировался, то в логине эти пароли должны совпадать и открываться окно.

**untitled1.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(985, 317)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 20, 281, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(45)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 300, 981, 20))
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.setObjectName("horizontalScrollBar")
        self.verticalScrollBar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(966, 0, 20, 301))
        self.verticalScrollBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalScrollBar.setObjectName("verticalScrollBar")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "YOU\'RE IN"))
```

**exm.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from untitled1 import Ui_MainWindow


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):           # MessengerApp  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**register.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(454, 569)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.011, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(182, 29, 212, 255), stop:1 rgba(48, 7, 182, 255));\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 0, 481, 31))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);")
        self.label_7.setText("")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(404, 7, 18, 18))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 8px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 162, 49);")
        self.pushButton_3.setText("")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 7, 18, 18))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 8px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 131, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 50, 561, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(27)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 250, 291, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 30px;")
        self.lineEdit_2.setMaxLength(300)
        self.lineEdit_2.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_2.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 160, 291, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 30px;")
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(300)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 370, 231, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 25px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(35, 237, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(52, 255, 143, 255))\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {    \n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(30, 209, 221, 255), stop:1 rgba(43, 214, 117, 255));\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Регистрация"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Регистрация"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Зарегестрируйтесь"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите пароль"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите логин"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Зарегестрироваться"))
```

**registermain.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from register import Ui_MainWindow


class RegApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):           # MessengerApp  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.myClose)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.myMinimize)
    
    def myClose(self):
        self.close()

    def myMinimize(self):
        self.showMinimized()     

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end-self.start
            self.setGeometry(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).x(),
                                self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).y(),
                                self.width(),
                                self.height())
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = RegApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**vxod.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(454, 569)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(454, 569))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(454, 569))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.011, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(182, 29, 212, 255), stop:1 rgba(48, 7, 182, 255));\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-20, 0, 481, 31))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);")
        self.label_7.setText("")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 7, 18, 18))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 8px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(404, 7, 18, 18))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 8px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 162, 49);")
        self.pushButton_3.setText("")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 160, 291, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 30px;")
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(300)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 370, 211, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(19)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 25px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(35, 237, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(52, 255, 143, 255))\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {    \n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(30, 209, 221, 255), stop:1 rgba(43, 214, 117, 255));\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 50, 171, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(31)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 250, 291, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 30px;")
        self.lineEdit_2.setMaxLength(300)
        self.lineEdit_2.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_2.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 320, 211, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(234, 234, 234);\n"
"background-color: transparent;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    color: rgb(177, 177, 177)\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Вход"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Вход"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите логин"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Войти"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Войдите"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите пароль"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Еще не зарегестрированы?"))
```

**vxodmain.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from vxod import Ui_MainWindow

from exm import ExampleApp
from registermain import RegApp


class VxodApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):           # MessengerApp  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.myClose)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.myMinimize)
               
        self.exampleApp = ExampleApp()                                # + создаем экэемпляр

        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.regClicked)
        self.exampleApp_1 = RegApp()

    def regClicked(self):
        self.exampleApp_1.show()                  # + показать новое окно пополнения


    def actionClicked(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())
        print(action.data())  

    def myClose(self):
        self.close()

    def myMinimize(self):
        self.showMinimized()     

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
        self.pressing = True

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pressing:
            self.end = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.movement = self.end-self.start
            self.setGeometry(self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).x(),
                                self.mapToGlobal(self.movement).y(),
                                self.width(),
                                self.height())
            self.start = self.end

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressing = False


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = VxodApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы объяснить лучше - что у вас не получается ?

Comment: Сделать регистрацию и логин, чтоб все работало и все пароли появлялись в какой нибудь датабазн, например текстовый документ

Comment: @S. Nick и в логине зарегестрированные пароли и логины работали, как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не предоставили демонстрацию своих попыток, сделать то, что вы хотите - это плохо.
Но учитывая ваше стремление к действиям, я вам продемонстрирую простенький пример.

Стартовый модуль `login.py` - создаст БД (`login.db`), в которой вы будете регистрировать пользователей.

Если это то, что вы хотели, вам надо будет применить это в своей программе.

**login.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

from welcome import MainWindow
from signup  import Dialog           
import sqlite3


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(496, 265)
        self.u_name_label = QLabel(Dialog)
        self.u_name_label.setGeometry(QRect(150, 110, 71, 20))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.u_name_label.setFont(font)
        self.u_name_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.u_name_label.setObjectName("u_name_label")
        self.pass_label = QLabel(Dialog)
        self.pass_label.setGeometry(QRect(150, 150, 71, 21))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pass_label.setFont(font)
        self.pass_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.pass_label.setObjectName("pass_label")
        self.uname_lineEdit = QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.uname_lineEdit.setGeometry(QRect(230, 110, 113, 20))
        self.uname_lineEdit.setObjectName("uname_lineEdit")
        self.pass_lineEdit = QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.pass_lineEdit.setGeometry(QRect(230, 150, 113, 20))
        self.pass_lineEdit.setObjectName("pass_lineEdit")
        self.login_btn = QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.login_btn.setGeometry(QRect(230, 200, 51, 23))
        self.login_btn.setObjectName("login_btn")
        self.signup_btn = QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.signup_btn.setGeometry(QRect(290, 200, 51, 23))
        self.signup_btn.setObjectName("signup_btn")
        self.label = QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(190, 10, 211, 51))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Login Form"))
        self.u_name_label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "USERNAME "))
        self.pass_label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PASSWORD"))
        self.login_btn.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Login"))
        self.signup_btn.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Sign Up"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Login Form"))


class LoginDatabase():
    def __init__(self, dbname):
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)

    def is_table(self, table_name):
        query = "SELECT name from sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{}';".format(table_name)
        cursor = self.conn.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result == None:
            return False
        else:
            return True


class MainDialog(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.loginDatabase = LoginDatabase('login.db')
        if self.loginDatabase.is_table('USERS'):
            pass
        else:
            self.loginDatabase.conn.execute("CREATE TABLE USERS(USERNAME TEXT NOT NULL, EMAIL TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT)")
            self.loginDatabase.conn.execute("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(?, ?, ?)", 
                                           ('admin', 'admin@gmail.com', 'admin') 
            )
            self.loginDatabase.conn.commit()

        self.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.loginCheck)
        self.signup_btn.clicked.connect(self.signUpCheck)        

    def showMessageBox(self, title, message):
        msgBox = QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
        msgBox.setWindowTitle(title)
        msgBox.setText(message)
        msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        msgBox.exec_()

    def welcomeWindowShow(self, username):
        self.welcomeWindow = MainWindow(username)
        self.welcomeWindow.show()

    def signUpShow(self):
        self.signUpWindow = Dialog(self)
        self.signUpWindow.show()

    def loginCheck(self):
        username = self.uname_lineEdit.text()
        password = self.pass_lineEdit.text()
        if (not username) or (not password):
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание!', 'Вы не заполнили все поля.')
            return

        result = self.loginDatabase.conn.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?",
                                                 (username, password))
        if len(result.fetchall()):     
            self.welcomeWindowShow(username)
            self.hide()
            self.loginDatabase.conn.close()
        else:
            self.showMessageBox('Внимание!', 'Неправильное имя пользователя или пароль.')

    def signUpCheck(self):
        self.signUpShow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app    = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainDialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**signup.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_signUp(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(570, 375)
        self.label = QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(160, 130, 81, 31))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QRect(160, 230, 81, 31))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QRect(160, 180, 81, 31))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.uname_lineEdit = QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.uname_lineEdit.setGeometry(QRect(250, 130, 141, 20))
        self.uname_lineEdit.setObjectName("uname_lineEdit")
        self.email_lineEdit = QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.email_lineEdit.setGeometry(QRect(250, 180, 141, 20))
        self.email_lineEdit.setObjectName("email_lineEdit")
        self.password_lineEdit = QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.password_lineEdit.setGeometry(QRect(250, 230, 141, 20))
        self.password_lineEdit.setObjectName("password_lineEdit")
        self.signup_btn = QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.signup_btn.setGeometry(QRect(270, 290, 75, 23))
        self.signup_btn.setObjectName("signup_btn")
        self.label_4 = QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QRect(150, 10, 321, 81))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "USERNAME"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "PASSWORD"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Email"))
        self.signup_btn.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Sign Up"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Create Account"))


class Dialog(QDialog, Ui_signUp):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent

        self.signup_btn.clicked.connect(self.insertData)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def insertData(self):
        username = self.uname_lineEdit.text()
        email    = self.email_lineEdit.text()
        password = self.password_lineEdit.text()

        if (not username) or (not email) or (not password):
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание!', 'Вы не заполнили все поля.')
            return

        result = self.parent.loginDatabase.conn.execute("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ?", (username,))
        if result.fetchall():
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание!', 'Пользоватеть с таким именем уже зарегистрирован.')
        else:
            self.parent.loginDatabase.conn.execute("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES(?, ?, ?)", 
                                                   (username, email, password))
            self.parent.loginDatabase.conn.commit()
            self.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app    = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**welcome.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(466, 283)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(120, 30, 231, 51))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QRect(140, 120, 211, 51))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добро пожаловать!"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Хорошего вам дня!"))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):          
    def __init__(self, name='admin'):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.label.setText('{} {}'.format(self.label.text(), name))
        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, это прямо то что мне нужно, теперь буду держать в голове этот пример и буду его использовать

Comment: @imapw_ если вы собираетесь  держать мой ответ в голове, то не забудьте отметить его как `Ответ полезен`. Это в верхнем левом углу моего ответа.

Comment: отметил как вы написали)