# Выполнения кода после ответа от сервера

Tags: python, pyqt

Как сделать чтоб код выполнялся лишь после ответа от запроса.Открывается окно с вводом пароля и логина после нажатия на кнопку "войти", выполняется функция clogging. Тут реализовано обновление токена через определенное время. Делается запрос на авторизацию и после если все верно переход на следующее окно.Проблема, в том что если сначала не зашел то будет False и он выходит и потом ввожу нормальные данные, то для него он все еще False и цикл проверки не работает.

main.py

```
    import sys
import time

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import sqlite3 as sq
import pandas as pd
import os
import requests as r
from PyQt5.uic.properties import QtGui

from env import Env
from rest_client import RestClient

app = None
widget = None


class Login(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, rest_client: RestClient):
        super(Login, self).__init__()
        loadUi("login.ui", self)
        self.singBtn.clicked.connect(self.clogging)
        self.infoLabel.hide()
        app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.closeEvent)
        self._rest_client = rest_client

    def closeEvent(self):
        print('close Login window')
        self._rest_client.log_out_user()

    def clogging(self):
        elma_user = self.email.text()
        elma_password = self.password.text()

        try:
            # Делается запрос на регистрацию
            self._rest_client.auth_user_with_update(elma_user, elma_password)
            # цикл проверки ответа если, ошибка то False, если все хорошо то True
            while True:

                if self._rest_client.is_authenticated():
                    widget.setCurrentIndex(1)
                    break
                elif self._rest_client.is_authenticated() is False:
                    break


        except Exception as e:
            print('Ошибка в кнопке', e)
            # self.infoLabel.setText(repr(e))
            # self.infoLabel.show()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    filename = None
    doc = None

    def __init__(self, rest_client):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("mainWindow.ui", self)
        self.excelBtn.clicked.connect(self.excelparsing)
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.openfile)
        self._rest_client = rest_client
        app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.closeEvent)

    def openfile(self):
        print('open file')
        filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self,
            'Open Excel File ',
            "",
            "Excel File (*.xlsx)"
        )

        if filename:
            print(filename)
            self.filename = filename

    def excelparsing(self):
        # widget.setCurrentIndex(0)

        self.doc = pd.read_excel(f"{self.filename}", usecols="A,C,L")

        con = sq.connect("products.db")
        cur = con.cursor()
        date = pd.DataFrame(self.doc)
        date.to_sql("details", con=con, if_exists="append", index=False)

    def closeEvent(self):
        print('close main window')
        self._rest_client.log_out_user()


def main():
    config = Env()
    rest_client = RestClient(config=config)
    global app
    global widget
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainapp = MainWindow(rest_client=rest_client)
    mainWindow = Login(rest_client=rest_client)

    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()

    widget.addWidget(mainWindow)
    widget.addWidget(mainapp)

    widget.setGeometry(500, 250, 400, 300)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Файл с запросами

```
       import time

import requests as r
from env import Env
import threading


class RestClient:
    def __init__(self, config: Env):
        self._api_token = config.elma_app_token
        self._http_rest = f"http://{config.rest_address}:{config.rest_port}/API/REST/"
        self.__auth_token__: str = ''
        self.__session_token__: str = ''
        self.__login__ = ''
        self.__password__ = ''
        self.__auth_token_livetime__ = config.auth_token_livetime
        self.__authenticated__ = None
        self.__retry_count__ = config.retry_count

    def auth_user(self):
        if not self.__password__.startswith('"') or not self.__password__.endswith('"'):
            password = self.__password__
        else:
            password = self.__password__.replace(' ', '')
        headers = {"ApplicationToken": self._api_token, "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
        session = r.Session()
        session.headers = headers

        try:
            response = session.post(
                f"{self._http_rest}/Authorization/LoginWith", params={"username": self.__login__},
                data=password
            )
            print(response.json())

            if (response.status_code in [400, 500]):
                self.__authenticated__ = False
                raise Exception('Ошибка авторизации или неверный пароль')

            data = response.json()
            self.__auth_token__ = data['AuthToken']
            self.__session_token__ = data['SessionToken']
            self.__authenticated__ = True

        except Exception as e:
            self.__authenticated__ = False
            print('Ошибка в auth_user', e)

        finally:
            session.close()

    def log_out_user(self):
        self.__auth_token__: str = ''
        self.__session_token__: str = ''
        self.__login__ = ''
        self.__password__ = ''
        self.__authenticated__ = False

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return self.__authenticated__

    def auth_user_with_update(self, login='', password=''):
        self.__login__ = login
        self.__password__ = password

        data_updater = threading.Thread(target=self.refresh_user_data, name='User token updater')
        data_updater.start()

    def refresh_user_data(self):
        current_retry = 0
        while True:
            try:
                self.auth_user()
                current_retry = 0
                time.sleep(2)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                current_retry += 1
                if current_retry > self.__retry_count__:
                    current_retry = 0
                    break
            if not self.__authenticated__ and current_retry == 0:
                break
```

Comment: По приведенным отрывкам, тяжело вам что-то посоветовать. Приведите минимальный пример, в котором будет видно структуру вашего приложения. И хорошо расскажите о действиях, которые вы выполняете. Например, нажали на кнопку такуе-то, перешли в метод ..., из него отправили запрос ..., получили результат запроса (покажите как он выглядит), проанализировали результат запроса и перешли туда ... или суда ... и так далее ...

Comment: Проверьте вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074711/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-pyqt5/1075113#1075113

Comment: @S.Nick,дополнил код